# Get pc Username from server page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 20 users in my server, i want to create project c# asp.net into server iis, when any user clicks on this page must show information (username, pc serial number, pc name, IP address  ,pc mac address )?

Comment: That's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Out of the list of what you want only getting an IP address is possible.

You can try following code snippet

```cs
var remoteIpAddress = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```